# Variable outside function scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I have function that reads json document, dayNames and monthNames are visible outside function, but date format isn't. Inside function it correctly prints its value but outside it doesn't update outside value. So why dateFormat doesn't update outside function?

```
var dayNames = [];
var monthNames = [];
var dateFormat = "";
$.getJSON("/Scripts/cldr/main/"+ culture + "/ca-gregorian.json", function (json) {
    $.each(json.main.@(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name).dates.calendars.gregorian.days.format.short, function (key, val) {
        dayNames.push(val);
    });
    $.each(json.main.@(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name).dates.calendars.gregorian.months["stand-alone"].wide, function (key, val) {
        monthNames.push(val);
    });
    dateFormat = json.main.@(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name).dates.calendars.gregorian.dateFormats.medium;
    console.log(dateFormat);  //Output: y-MM-dd
});
console.log(dateFormat); //Output:
```

Comment: this is due that `console.log(dateFormat);` is executed before the `$.getJSON()` callback

Comment: `$.getJSON()` is async. `dateFormat` is not yet available in the "outer" `console.log()`

Comment: Reason is outside "console.log(dateFormat);" is getting executed before your getJSON callback

Comment: dateFormat is a global variable should be updated..unless ajax is moving too fast

Comment: And why dayNames/monthNames are available then? Is it "random"?

Comment: @Erndob `dateFormat` is also available it's just that you are printing `dateFormat` right after the `$.getJSON` you aren't doing the same for `dayNames` or `monthNames` you would see the same behavior if you did...

Comment: @brso05 hmm, I guess you are right. I didn't try console log, but I used dayNames and monthNames in jquery ui datepicker with success, while dateFormat failed, but now that I look at it, it's perhaps just that format isn't supported by jquery-ui.

But I have another question then, I have dayNames/monthNames in "    $("#date").datepicker({monthNames: monthNames, dayNamesMin:dayNames});" and it works, but even if I put console.log(monthNames) after that it still doesn't print anything. Why?

Comment: @Erndob by the time you click on your `datepicker` the variables have been initialized...

Comment: @brs05 I see. Thanks a lot. It's a lot clearer now.

Comment: @Erndob no problem man glad I could help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is `$.getJSON()` is an asynchronous call.  The `console.log(dateFomrat)` outside the function runs before the function finishes. The code continues while the `$.getJSON()` is running so `dateFormat` isn't set when the second(outside) `console.log()` executes.

Comment: Why dayNames and monthNames are updated then?  I tried giving value to dateFormat before other two values, but result was the same. I don't understand this. If two cycles take some time to complete, and because of that outside log executes before dateFormat got value, giving it value before two cycles should fix that but that's not the case. Could you explain me why?

Comment: @Erndob try printing dayNames  and monthNames outside of getJSON, it will not update the value until getJSON  callback is executed

Comment: @Erndob `dateFormat` is also available it's just that you are printing `dateFormat` right after the `$.getJSON` you aren't doing the same for `dayNames` or `monthNames` you would see the same behavior if you did...

Comment: @Erndob `dateFormat` is updated just not before the outside `console.log()` runs...